# Should we use Curl or cURL in documentation?

Tags: curl

The official spelling, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL), is cURL.

However, if you search online, the majority of documentation and technical articles seem to use either Curl or curl.

What is the most appropriate spelling for documentation and article writing?

Answer (score 2):

curl. That is how they spell it on their [documentation and man page](https://www.mit.edu/afs.new/sipb/user/ssen/src/curl-7.11.1/docs/curl.html).